# how to make this line of code recheck if the old program is still there

Tags: inno-setup

So the line of code i found and modified little, checks if there is older version of the program installed, and offers to remove it. But how to make it recheck again? as if it asks "do you want to uninstall" and i press yes then it shows the uninstall msgbox of old one and when i press NO as not to uninstall, the new installer still lets move on and install.

```
[code]
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  Result := True;

  if CurPageID = wpWelcome then
  begin
    Result := False;
    if Exec(ExpandConstant('WHAT TO PUT HERE?'), '', '', 
      SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
    begin
      if ResultCode = 0 then    
        Result := True
      else
        MsgBox('#COMMENT#', mbCriticalError, MB_OK);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

what needs to be modified in this line of code so i can use it for my purpose?

Comment: See [setup exit codes](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupexitcodes), then 'ResultCode' in [Exec](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupexitcodes).

Comment: IOW, check 'iResultCode' in your code. If it's not 0, uninstallation did not complete.

Comment: @jryka - My comments were addressed to your original question. You were executing an uninstaller. I have no idea why you have changed and asking another question now.

Comment: To make it clear, the exit code I commented about is valid for an Inno Setup uninstaller. I don't know anything about an Authorization.exe.